# How can I avoid validation of fields when the rowEditor is clicked?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable element where I use a rowEditor. Additionally it is possible to add a new record which is implemented as inputFields in the footer of the table. All elements are validated. The problem is, that when a user hits the rowEditor the validation complains that the values for a new record are not set.

How can I avoid that the new record fields are being validated when the rowEditor is clicked?

I fiddled around a bit with proccess & immediate on the ajax events but I'm not able to figure this out. Is this possible and if yes, how? I'm thankful for help.

```
<p:dataTable var="contact"
    value="#{data.activeCustomer.contacts.toArray()}"
    id="contactsTable"
    emptyMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Administration/noRecordsFoundSearch')}"
    editable="true">

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{logic.onEdit(contact)}" />
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{logic.onCancel}" />

    <f:facet name="header">  
                            #{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Administration/Contacts/labelContacts')}
                        </f:facet>

    <p:column
        headerText="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Administration/Contacts/prename')}">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{contact.prename}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText required="true"
                    requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/CustomerAdministration/Validation/enterPrename')}"
                    value="#{contact.prename}"></p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:inputText required="true"
                requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/CustomerAdministration/Validation/enterPrename')}"
                value="#{data.contactPrename}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>

    <p:column
        headerText="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Administration/Contacts/surname')}">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{contact.surname}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText required="true"
                    requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/CustomerAdministration/Validation/enterSurname')}"
                    value="#{contact.surname}"></p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:inputText required="true"
                requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/CustomerAdministration/Validation/enterSurname')}"
                value="#{data.contactSurname}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>

    <p:column
        headerText="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Administration/Contacts/phone')}">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{contact.phone}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{contact.phone}"
                    requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/CustomerAdministration/Validation/enterPhone')}"
                    required="true"></p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:inputText
                requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/CustomerAdministration/Validation/enterPhone')}"
                required="true" value="#{data.contactPhone}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>

    <p:column
        headerText="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Administration/Contacts/email')}">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{contact.email}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{contact.email}" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/CustomerAdministration/Validation/enterEmail')}">
                    <f:validator validatorId="EmailValidator" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:inputText required="true"
                requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/CustomerAdministration/Validation/enterEmail')}"
                value="#{data.contactEmail}">
                <f:validator validatorId="EmailValidator" />
            </p:inputText>
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width: 6%"
        headerText="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/CustomerAdministration/actionsColumnTitle')}">
        <p:rowEditor />

        <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"
            actionListener="#{logic.deleteContact(contact)}"
            icon="ui-icon-trash" update=":#{p:component('contactForm')}"
            immediate="true" />

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:commandButton
                value="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Administration/Contacts/ButtonAddContact')}"
                actionListener="#{logic.addContact}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: it is because of required="true" for h:inputText in every columns footer. I feel ideally you should validate on click of save button  or something.

Comment: @SrikanthGanji: Thanks for your comment. I know that this is the issue but I think it is possible to keep that validation there. I would like to do a client-side validation on that point.